# Django Python besides uploading text, i would like to be able to upload image and videos

Tags: python, django, image, video, upload

I work on a Social Media Website. I get the Base code from an Open Source Project on GitHub.
On my Website you can only upload Text, and link some images, but these are not very user friendly.
I would love to be able to upload images and videos besides the Text.

When I watch Tutorials on YouTube, it's always very hard to implement that code to mine.

Is there a way that someone could help me?

The code of post_form.html, post_detail.html, forms.py, views.py, models.py, urls.py, admin.py, settings.py are under this text:

post_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Post{% endblock %}
{% block content %}



<div class="m-auto w-100 container">
<div class="content-section">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Post</legend>
            {{form.media}}
            {{form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Crop the photo</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="max-width: 100%; overflow:auto">
            <img style="max-height:100%; max-width: 100%" src="" id="image">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="float-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-zoom-in">
                    <i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-zoom-out">
                    <i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-and-upload">Crop and upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</section>
<style>
    .content-section{
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    a{
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #000;
    }
    .btn-post{
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Lato' sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0px 70px 0px 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .btn-cancel{
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    }
    .post header{
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
        padding: 17px 0;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .content-section{
        border: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
      }
      
</style>


{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script>
        function picupload(){
            const imgf = document.getElementById('id_image')
            imgf.click()
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Post{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-md-10 m-auto">
    
<article class="content-section" style="overflow: auto;">

    <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}" alt="image">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="d-inline"><a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'profile-detail-view' post.author.pk %}">{{ post.author }}</a></h4>
            <div id="save-section">
                {% include 'blog/save_section.html' %}
            </div>
            <p><small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="d-inline"><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
    {% if post.author == user %}
        <div class="d-inline float-right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btnedit" href="{% url 'post-update' post.id %}"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btndel" href="{% url 'post-delete' post.id %}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        </div>
    {% endif %} 
    

    <hr>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|safe }}</p>
    <hr>
    <div id="like-section">
        {% include 'blog/like_section.html' %}
    </div>
</article>




<hr>

<div class="main-comment-section">
    {% include 'blog/comments.html' %}
</div>


<br><br>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import fields
from .models import Post, Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control custom-txt','cols':'40','rows':'3'}), label='')
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body',]
```

views.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from notification.models import Notification
from django.core.checks import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Comment, Post
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from users.models import Profile
from itertools import chain
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import random

""" Home page with all posts """
def first(request):
    context = {
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/first.html', context)

""" Posts of following user profiles """
@login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    posts = []
    qs = None
    for u in users:
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.user.post_set.all()
        posts.append(p_posts)
    my_posts = profile.profile_posts()
    posts.append(my_posts)
    if len(posts)>0:
        qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj:obj.date_posted)

    paginator = Paginator(qs, 50)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  
    return render(request,'blog/feeds.html',{'profile':profile,'posts':posts_list})


""" Post Like """
@login_required
def LikeView(request):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=request.user, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
        notify = Notification(post=post, sender=request.user, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.save()

    context = {
        'post':post,
        'total_likes':post.total_likes(),
        'liked':liked,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Post save """
@login_required
def SaveView(request):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    saved = False
    if post.saves.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.saves.remove(request.user)
        saved = False
    else:
        post.saves.add(request.user)
        saved = True
    
    context = {
        'post':post,
        'total_saves':post.total_saves(),
        'saved':saved,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/save_section.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Like post comments """
@login_required
def LikeCommentView(request): # , id1, id2              id1=post.pk id2=reply.pk
    post = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    cliked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        cliked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        cliked = True

    cpost = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('pid'))
    total_comments2 = cpost.comments.all().order_by('-id')
    total_comments = cpost.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
    tcl={}
    for cmt in total_comments2:
        total_clikes = cmt.total_clikes()
        cliked = False
        if cmt.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            cliked = True

        tcl[cmt.id] = cliked


    context = {
        'comment_form':CommentForm(),
        'post':cpost,
        'comments':total_comments,
        'total_clikes':post.total_clikes(),
        'clikes':tcl
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Home page with all posts """
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data()
        users = list(User.objects.exclude(pk=self.request.user.pk))
        if len(users) > 3:
            cnt = 3
        else:
            cnt = len(users)
        random_users = random.sample(users, cnt)
        context['random_users'] = random_users
        return context


""" All the posts of the user """
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')



""" Post detail view """
def PostDetailView(request,pk):

    stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
    total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
    total_saves = stuff.total_saves()
    total_comments = stuff.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
    total_comments2 = stuff.comments.all().order_by('-id')

    context = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        comment_qs = None
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            form = request.POST.get('body')
            reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            if reply_id:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
            
            comment = Comment.objects.create(name=request.user,post=stuff,body=form, reply=comment_qs)
            comment.save()
            if reply_id:
                notify = Notification(post=stuff, sender=request.user, user=stuff.author, text_preview=form, notification_type=4)
                notify.save()
            else:
                notify = Notification(post=stuff, sender=request.user, user=stuff.author, text_preview=form, notification_type=3)
                notify.save()
            total_comments = stuff.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
            total_comments2 = stuff.comments.all().order_by('-id')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
             

    tcl={}
    for cmt in total_comments2:
        total_clikes = cmt.total_clikes()
        cliked = False
        if cmt.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            cliked = True

        tcl[cmt.id] = cliked
    context["clikes"]=tcl


    liked = False
    if stuff.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True
    context["total_likes"]=total_likes
    context["liked"]=liked


    saved = False
    if stuff.saves.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        saved = True
    context["total_saves"]=total_saves
    context["saved"]=saved
    

    context['comment_form'] = comment_form

    context['post']=stuff
    context['comments']=total_comments

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)


""" Create post """
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields =['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)



""" Update post """
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields =['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


""" Delete post """
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False



""" Search by post title or username """
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['query']
    if len(query) >= 150 or len(query) < 1:
        allposts = Post.objects.none()
    elif len(query.strip()) == 0:
        allposts = Post.objects.none()
    else:
        allpostsTitle = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        allpostsAuthor = Post.objects.filter(author__username = query)
        allposts = allpostsAuthor.union(allpostsTitle)
    
    params = {'allposts': allposts}
    return render(request, 'blog/search_results.html', params)


""" Liked posts """
@login_required
def AllLikeView(request):
    user = request.user
    liked_posts = user.blogpost.all()
    context = {
        'liked_posts':liked_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/liked_posts.html', context)


""" Saved posts """
@login_required
def AllSaveView(request):
    user = request.user
    saved_posts = user.blogsave.all()
    context = {
        'saved_posts':saved_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/saved_posts.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


""" Post model """
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blogpost", blank=True)
    saves = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blogsave", blank=True)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def total_saves(self):
        return self.saves.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"pk":self.pk})


""" Comment model """
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments" , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blogcomment", blank=True)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name="replies", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def total_clikes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s' %(self.post.title, self.name, self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import AllSaveView, PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView, SaveView, UserPostListView, LikeView,LikeCommentView, posts_of_following_profiles,  AllLikeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.first, name='firsthome'),
    path('home/', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('feed/', posts_of_following_profiles, name='posts-follow-view'),
    path('post/user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView, name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/like/', LikeView, name='post-like'),
    path('liked-posts/', AllLikeView, name='all-like'),
    path('post/save/', SaveView, name='post-save'),
    path('saved-posts/', AllSaveView, name='all-save'),
    path('post/comment/like/', LikeCommentView, name='comment-like'),
    path('trends/', views.trends, name='blog-trends'),
    path('settings/', views.settings, name='blog-settings'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog-blog'),
    path('termsofuse/', views.termsofuse, name='blog-termsofuse'),
    path('termsofusede/', views.termsofusede, name='blog-termsofusede'),
    path('termsofuseit/', views.termsofuseit, name='blog-termsofuseit'),
    path('termsofusees/', views.termsofusees, name='blog-termsofusees'),
    path('termsofusefr/', views.termsofusefr, name='blog-termsofusefr'),
    path('termsofusetr/', views.termsofusetr, name='blog-termsofusetr'),
    path('privacypolicy/', views.privacypolicy, name='blog-privacypolicy'),
    path('cookies/', views.cookies, name='blog-cookies'),
    path('press/', views.press, name='blog-press'),
    path('helpcenter/', views.helpcenter, name='blog-helpcenter'),

]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Comment, Post
from . import forms
from . import models


admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

# Loading ENV
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_cleanup',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'ckeditor',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'notification',
    'chat',
    'channels',
    'friend',
    'image_uploader_widget',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'users/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'width':'auto',
    },
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')     # environment variable containing username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASS')  # environment variable containing password

GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY")

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
        messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
        messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
        messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
        messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default":{
        "BACKEND":"channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    },
}

SITE_ID = 2     # considering 2nd site in 'Sites' to be 127.0.0.1 (for dev)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    },
    'github': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'user',
            'repo',
            'read:org',
        ],
    }
}
```

What code do I need to implement to make images and video uploadable?

Comment: Please describe what your current issue is. Stackoverflow is not intended to write code for you.

Comment: If you don't know where to start with Django, you can check this tutorial from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django). It will help you to understand every layer of Django. You need to add ImageField to your Comment model, form and HTML to be able to use it. But, if you're not sure where to start, try to invest some time in Django itself.